# Create a table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links

I'm new in LaTeX, and I want to create a TOC like this one

[image: The required output]

TIP: every red box is a link to a certain area in the article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the normal Table Of Content you get while using

```
\tableofcontents
```

To achieve the links you need to use the `hyperref` package

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

A full example would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

   \tableofcontents

\section{foo}
  \subsection{bar}

\section{foo 2}
  \subsection{bar 2}
  \subsection{bar 3}

\end{document}
```

The rest is done automatically